# Google StackDrive Logging Level in containers with uwsgi always at Error Level

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, uwsgi, stackdriver

I'm deploying via Kuberenetes come containers on Google Cloud, which are django project and uwsgi to run them.

I'm using the stackdrive logging tool to see the logging, the problem is that all the entries are seen as severity `ERROR` even thought they are not error. It seems that the log of `uwsgi` is written to `stderr` or something like that.

In the picture you can see that django uses `INFO` level, but that is received as `ERROR` by stackdrive.

[image]

this is how i set up uwsgi.

`[uwsgi]
master = true
socket = :3031
chdir = .
wsgi-file = docker.wsgi
processes = 4
threads = 2
socket-timeout = 90
harakiri = 90
http = :8000
env = prometheus_multiproc_dir=multi
enable-threads = yes
lazy-apps = yes
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes logs written to `stderr` are always tagged as ERROR -- this is hard-coded in the Stackdriver logging agent. Similarly, logs written to `stdout` are always tagged with INFO.

If you can configure your application to write non-error log messages to `stdout`, please do so. Another possible approach is to write the logs to a file, run the "`tail -f`" command on that file as a sidecar container in the same pod, and looking for your logs in Stackdriver Logs Viewer under the sidecar container instead. Finally, you might consider writing your logs directly into the [Stackdriver Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write), which gives you full control over the contents of each entry.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for this. I've been scratching my head as to why these logs all look like 'errors'.

Comment: To add to my answer, if you are able to write logs to stdout/stderr in JSON format, the logging agent will parse them into structured payloads, and the "severity" field in the payload will override the hard-coded severity.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021206/1357387) answer helped me find the solution to this. Using the option `logger-req=stdio` uWSGI logs get the correct level in Stackdriver.

Example of `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
logger-req=stdio
```